# Find the value of: $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, harmonic-numbers

> Calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right).$$

I tried relating it to a Riemann sum, but I couldn't see how to do so.

Comment: This has been asked here *many* times before.

Comment: Impossible duplicate imho.

Answer (score 1):

For large $n$:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n+1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} &\approx \int_n^{2n} \frac{1}{x} \,dx\\
&=\ln 2n - \ln n \\
&= \ln 2
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{n+k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\frac kn}=\int_1^2\frac{dx}x=\log2$$